# How does JET OLEDB Parameters compare strings with text field in and Access DB

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2007, oledb, jet

I have the following update query in C# using a JET OLEDB connection, connecting to a ms access DB file. The query fails to change the fields, it runs correctly but just 0 rows changed.

I think the problem is how parameters are processed and compared against the DB but have no idea how to fix it.

The "User" column is set as text. I have an insert statement that works perfectly set up in the same fashion with the parameters.

```
com.CommandText = "UPDATE [ExamMaster] SET [User] =  (DLookup('LName', 'Users', 'ID' = '@correctUser') WHERE [User] = '@user'";

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correctUser", correctUser);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userName);
```

If I do not use a parameter for the where clause and just insert it into the command string like so:

```
WHERE [User] = '"+userName+"'";</code>
```

it will update the DB just fine. What am I missing here? 
UPDATE:
With or with single quotes makes no difference and rearranging the order of the parameters does not work either.

Comment: Try removing the quotes and using a string literal: `@"UPDATE [ExamMaster] SET [User] =  (DLookup(""LName"", ""Users"", ""ID = @correctUser"") WHERE [User] = @user";`

Answer (score 1):

The order matters.  I "think" in your query `user` is being called first before the `correctUser` due to the DLOOKUP function.

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userName);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correctUser", correctUser);
```

You don't need to single quote parameters:

```
WHERE [User] = @user";
```

and I'll guess that the DLOOKUP doesn't need the single quotes either, just [brackets] if the field name has a space or is a reserved word (which [User] might be).

Comment: I found out that Access doesnt support named parameters but will still accept them, but you have to make sure the order you add them in is the same as the query

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change that a bit, try:

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(aconnectionstring);
cn.Open();

//testing
int correctUser = 1;
string userName = "1";

OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
com.Connection = cn;

//You cannot have a parameter in DLookUp
com.CommandText = "UPDATE [ExamMaster] SET [User] = " +
   "DLookup('LName', 'Users', 'ID = " + correctUser + "') WHERE [User] = @user";

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userName);

//You must execute the query
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```